# Linear independece of linear functionals on vector space of all polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

This is from an example of a textbook that I didn't totally understand.

*Let's suppose $V$ is the vector space of all polynomials functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ which have degree less than or equal to 2. 
 Let  $t_1$, $t_2$ and $t_3$ three distinct real numbers and let $$L_i(p) = p(t_i)$$*

Then $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$ are linear functionals on $V$ and they are linear independent. 
Now, for proving that statement I put $$ 0 = c_1L_1+c_2L_2+c_3L_3 $$
for all $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$  **and** for each $p$ in $V$, and this should give us  $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$ 
How can I prove that for all  $p$ in $V$?  I was thinking on considering a basis for the polynomials but then I'll introduce new scalars different from $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ and I got things messed up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that

$$0=c_1p(t_1)+c_2p(t_2)+c_3p(t_3),\quad \forall p\in V$$

only holds when $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$. By example: define polynomials $p_k$ such that $p_k(t_j)=1-\delta_{k,j}$ where $\delta_{k,j}$ is the Kronecker delta (these polynomials can be defined explicitly using the Lagrange polynomials, if you need to prove it existence).

Then you have an homogeneous system of equations

$$0=c_1+c_2,\quad 0=c_1+c_3,\quad 0=c_2+c_3$$

what imply that $-c_1=c_2=c_3$, so all constant are zero.$\Box$

Comment: Sorry, if I define particular polynomials like those, the assertion $\forall p\in V$  still holds?

Comment: the unique solution $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ holds for any polynomial $p$